# Exclude help requests and redirects from the API limit

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Help API requests probably should not count towards the no-key API limit. The most likely usage scenario of the API without a key is when people are trying to learn it, which means reading the help a lot.

It also doesn't help either that the `<method>?help` form redirects and generates two requests towards the limit count.

**Update:** People have discovered that [if the first request does not have a key, that sets the daily limit](https://stackapps.com/questions/158/the-api-key-does-not-work). It's unlikely devs will remember to add their key when making a request to an API in the browser to read the help (ie `/stats?help`), thus triggering the 300 daily cap.

Answer (score 2):

Well, *[looks around]* you could use a proxy to get more requests.

But I'm guessing your best bet is to take out a key.