# The API Key does not work

Tags: support, bug, rate-limit, obsolete

I have registered an app at https://stackapps.com/apps/register, got a Key right away after I have submitted.

But now when I request http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/stats?key=MYKEY, I got RequestLimitExceeded Error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "RequestLimitExceeded",
    "message": "This IP has exceeded the request-per-day limit."
  }
}
```

Note: I have reached 300 requests, but not 10k for sure :)

---

Ok, Now I fixed it by changing my IP Address (Glad I am at home)

```
X-RateLimit-Max 100000
X-RateLimit-Current 99998
```

---

And I just noticed that key is need to set for the first time only.

Once first request is success and got `X-RateLimit-Max` in response header, you don't need to set key an API URL anymore for the whole day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you make any requests earlier today without a key?

The API only checks your key and sets a limit on the first request.

> A single IP address can only make a limited number of requests per day to the API. This limit is determined at **first request time**, and is dependent upon the presence of an API key.

Comment: I did requests with and without API Key before reaching 300, but the very first request was without key.

Comment: If the first request was without a key, than your limit today is 300.

Comment: This happened to my app too.

Comment: Is that quote "quoted" from somewhere specific?  (I can't find the second sentence anywhere "official".)

Answer (score 2):

A [help request in the browser will trigger](https://stackapps.com/questions/127/exclude-help-requests-and-redirects-from-the-api-limit) the daily max cap. The SO team has set different request limits on the help requests (yesterday it was 300, but today it's 100000). So, by making `stats?help` (no key) request your first request for the day, you're 'hacking' your daily cap to 100000. :-)

I suspect this hack won't last long, so use it while it's there...

Comment: What a dumb way to do it. Oh well.

Comment: Just by browsing any page on api.stackoverflow.com without key will make your daily limit to 300 I guess