# Can we not limit requests based on the first one?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, obsolete

According to the answer given to [this](https://stackapps.com/questions/158/) question, it seems like the API limits requests based on the first one. (Regardless of the presence of a key.)

Can this please be changed? It really hinders development.

---

**Edit:** this is quite serious. My mobile site quickly used up its 300 requests - even though it's using a key now.

Comment: By the time your development is serious enough to go through 300 requests in a day you should be using a key on all requests.  Its only a hindrance in the first 24 hours if you do so.

Comment: @Kevin: Exactly. It's those first hours that are the problem.

Comment: those first few hours aren't worth the trouble.

Comment: @Kevin: They may not be... but I am suffering the consequences right now.

Comment: Pretty sure this hasn't been an issue for years and I can't repro it now. Should be tagged `status-completed`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Completely agree.

It seems this could be implemented as a simple check for the key:

```
if (keyispresent && keyisvalid && currentlimit < keylimit)
    currentlimit = keylimit;
```

I don't think this would incur much overhead.

Comment: Ya. Consider this: a user visits a page that makes an API request via AJAX *without* a key. Suddenly, through no fault of theirs, they are limited to 300.

Comment: That's why I said "<"

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use it to boost your daily cap to 100000. :-)

Help requests trigger different daily limit, so if your first request for the day is `stats?help`, you get that limit instead of the API key limit or the no key limit.

Comment: I don't think that's a viable solution... especially for the end users.

Comment: I don't expect the end users to be making no key requests. They would be using an already developed app that comes with a key.

Comment: You never know...