# Guidance on usage thresholds - specifically throttling

Tags: discussion, api, limits, libraries, obsolete

I am running a lot of tests and have started to get 403 errors.

I am using a key and certainly have not exceeded my quota.

Am I running foul of some yet unmentioned throttling threshold and if so, what measures should I emplace in order to not be surprised by 403s etc?

Comment: Ran into this myself early on. See this question for more info: http://stackapps.com/questions/160/

Comment: I think he should get "RequestLimitExceeded" Error JSON, if that is the case, but his problem looks more like from DOS Protection mechanism for me.

Comment: any json returns? what about http response headers? how many requests did you make per minute?

Comment: There should be a JSON response (with some additional information) if the API is cutting you off, are you seeing anything like that?

Comment: Key behavior has changed to handle the "multiple app" scenario, so alternating between `Key` and `No Key` shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @kev - wasn't looking. am now. will update with observations.

Comment: Never updated with the promised observations and not reproducible. Probably hasn't been an issue for years.