# Key Limit is 10k or 100k?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, rate-limit

Getting Started FAQ Question says 10k

[API "Hello World" code](https://stackapps.com/questions/2/getting-started-with-the-api)

But I see 100k on Response Header

```
X-RateLimit-Max 100000
X-RateLimit-Current 99993
```

Just typo in nginx setting or something like that? or Just temporarily? or Can we keep like that? :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: generic "motivator" image]

Its 10k now, the way it was intended.  Anyone with an active lease will stick to 100k until the day ends, or an update is deployed.

Answer (score 0):

This is most definitely a mistake.

But I am all for changing it to 100000 - not that I need it (thanks to [this](https://stackapps.com/questions/158/) bug).